# Pass parameters in body to post in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am facing issue posting values as parameters with jQuery post method with the script as per below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var params = {
        // Request parameters
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://someurl.com/bravsoap.asmx?op=ptr" + $.param(params),
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","text/xml");
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: "{body}",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
</script>
```

This is sample from API vendor:

```
<ptr_PostToRoom xmlns="http://someurl.com">
    <SessionID>9283-243342-422323423-2343e</SessionID>
    <PostingM>PostingMethod_RoomID</PostingM>
    <PostingP>002</PostingP>
    <Header>
        <Code>FOOD</Code>
        <Description>Crystal Room â€“ Beverage â€“ Order No. 12345</Description>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    </Header>
    <Transactions>
        <Code>FOOD</Code>
        <Description>Dinner</Description>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <GrossTotal>35.50</GrossTotal>

        <Code>BARDRINK</Code>
        <Description>Bar Drinks</Description>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <GrossTotal>12.75</GrossTotal>
</ptr_PostToRoom>
```

Sorry for the bad explanation in first place.

Comment: If it's a POST request the params should be placed in the body. If you *really* want to send the data in the URL then you're missing the `&` in the URL: `...bravsoap.asmx?op=ptr&" + $.param(params),`

Comment: hi Rory, this is basically trial of API here and the code you see above is all provided without params I have inputed below \\REQUESTED PARAMS. Rest of the doc is with <soap> tags which is fine but I dont know how to then send soap tag over the script above? does data: {body}, sends it?  where do I then place soap in the body of the page?

Comment: it does also fail if I do & with the previous parameters passed in var params